# How to delete node_modules when intellij is open without closing intellij? win 10 - folder is in use

Tags: intellij-idea

How to delete node_modules when intellij is open without closing intellij? win 10 - folder is in use

I can't figure out how is supposed to work... I tried to delete the node_modules folder from explorer and says is in use by intellij. It's so annoying and I need to close intellij and open again..

I know it can be done with process explorer, but still, I don't think this should even be a problem..

Comment: What happens if you try deleting it in the project view of the IDE?

Comment: that works most of the time, but sometimes I'd like to delete from cmd